# How to eliminate empty csv records from Java arraylist?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have requirement where I need to fetch few values and then write all those to csv file. To achieve this, I am adding the values to Java Arraylist and writing to a csv file. But when I do this Its writing the records to CSV but with empty rows in between records. Not sure why this problem is coming.

```
1,abc,fname,lname,email,log


1,abc1,fname1,lname1,email1,log1
1,abc2,fname2,lname2,email2,log2


1,abc3,fname3,lname3,email3,log3
1,abc4,fname4,lname4,email4,log4
```

here is my code. Please let me know what's wrong with this code:

```
public StringBuilder fetchUsers() {
    ArrayList<String> users = null;
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        client = getMyClient();
        if (client != null) {
            UserList usersList = getUsers();
            if (usersList.totalCount != 0 && usersList.totalCount >= 1) {
                System.out.println("usersList.totalCount ----->"
                        + usersList.totalCount);

                for (KalturaUser user : usersList.objects) {
                    users = new ArrayList<String>();
                    if (user != null) {
                        String action = null;
                        String userFullName = null;
                        String modifiedName = null;
                        String firstName = user.firstName;
                        if (user.id != null) {
                            String cnum = getUserUniqueId(user.id);
                            String userRole = getUserRole(user.id);
                            if (cnum != null || userRole != null) {
                                action = validateCnum(cnum, userRole);
                                if (!action.equals("3")) {
                                    users.add(action);
                                    users.add(cnum);
                                    if (firstName != null
                                            && firstName.contains("@")) {
                                        user.email = firstName;
                                        userFullName = getUserNames(user.id);
                                        firstName = userFullName;
                                    }
                                    users.add(firstName);
                                    users.add(user.lastName);
                                    users.add(user.email);
                                    users.add(userRole);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    allUsers.add(users);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (MyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    writeToCSV();
    return sb1;
}


private void writeToCSV() {
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter = null;
    CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(System
            .getProperty("line.separator"));
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:/users.csv");
        csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);
        csvFilePrinter.printRecord(USER_COLUMNS);
        for (List<String> rowData : allUsers) {
            csvFilePrinter.printRecord(rowData);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getStackTrace());
    } finally {
        try {
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
            csvFilePrinter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter/csvPrinter!");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
 allUsers.add(users);
```

should be inside the `if (user != null)` and all the sub-ifs

Something like this:

```
if (user != null) {
...
    if (user.id != null) {

        ...
        if (cnum != null || userRole != null) {
            ....
            if (!action.equals("3")) {
                users = new ArrayList<String>();
                ....
                allUsers.add(users);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In general, you should create the array and add it to the `allUsers` only if you have something to add

Comment: Yes @Roman this would be the issue. From the code I felt this issue only.

Comment: @Roman - I have applied the change you mentioned. But still same issue.

Comment: You have put it inside the `if (!action.equals("3"))`?

Comment: @Roman - Thank you so much. Now its working. I understood the concept too. Many thanks to Stack exchange too to learn lot of things while working.